# Problem to install Mixpanel SDK - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sdk, mixpanel

I need to configure the mixpanel in my work and for that I created a test project to understand how to configure the mixpanel SDK.

I followed the basic examples in the documentation.
https://github.com/davodesign84/react-native-mixpanel

But I'm having a problem:  'null is not an object (evaluating RNMixpnael.sharedInstanceWithToken)'.

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import Mixpanel from 'react-native-mixpanel';

Mixpanel.sharedInstanceWithToken("MY_PROJECT_TOKEN");

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
       <Text>Testing Mixpanel SDK</Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And the error:

[image]

Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this issue only for Android? Have you tried iOS?

Comment: Have you run pod install https://github.com/davodesign84/react-native-mixpanel#autolinking-and-rn--060? What is the version of the react-native library in your project?

Comment: You should make sure "MY_PROJECT_TOKEN" is not null and have an actual value

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani I tried hard coding the value but I still get the issue. It also works fine on iOS.

Comment: whats the react native version? >=0.60 will have auto linking otherwise you need to link the library. The error says Mixpanel instance is null, not an issue with token

Comment: @Wolverine react-native is 0.63.3.

Comment: @RoniCastro react-native-mixpanel is ^1.2.3. The issue is only with Android so I dont think pod install will fix this.

Comment: Have you tried doing this Firebase step "Additional info for Android (version >= 1.1.2)" https://github.com/davodesign84/react-native-mixpanel#additional-info-for-android-version--112? Apparently it is necessary in your version. I have in my project push notification from mixpanel, but I am not 100% sure it is necessary everything if you don't use it, but I would give a try in adding at least the `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1'` and related code in build.gradle and the service.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding this line to `MainApplication.java`

```
import com.kevinejohn.RNMixpanel.RNMixpanel;
```

Answer (score 0):

In react-native versions newer than 0.60 auto-linking should work. All you have to do is:

1. **install react-native-mixpanel** using npm or yarn
2. **add `pod 'Mixpanel'` to your Podfile**, initialize it with the token

   More info here: https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ios
3. **run `pod install` inside ios folder** <-- usually missing this or not restarting the JS server is the cause
4. **import it in your RN codd**: `import Mixpanel from 'react-native-mixpanel';` as you did

If the null error still shows up just make sure JS server is stopped, remove Xcode derived data, clean cache (`npx watchman watch-del-all && yarn start --reset-cache`) and rebuild. It should work.

Comment: Whats the difference between "import com.kevinejohn.RNMixpanel.*;" and "import com.kevinejohn.RNMixpanel.RNMixpanel" ?

Comment: @Evanss the idea in my answer is that the pod needs to be installed. I updated my answer. The question is for iOS, not for android. Thank you for your comment. It made me aware that I added an Android import instead of an iOS import (step 2) and I corrected that line.